# Clients of Bind Ubuntu Server Not Finding Sites After Update

Tags: networking, server, samba, dns, openvpn

I currently have one server (ServerA) that runs OpenVPN and Bind9.  I have another server (ServerB) that runs Samba and a LAMP stack.  They're both running Ubuntu 16.10.

They've been running just fine, I've rebooted both multiple times, and never had an issue.  Today, I connected to ServerA and ran the updates it needed that I had been neglecting.  When it came back on, I tried updating ServerB, and it failed connecting to any repositories.  I tried pinging Google.com, Facebook.com, and got nothing from ServerB either. 
From ServerB:

```
nslookup google.com
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.237, trying next server
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.8.206
```

and

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

I'm a fair novice with DNS and the like, but I can't find what could have broken it.

Bind9.service is running on ServerA and I've made no edits since originally setting it up.  UFW is active and allows port 53 and Bind9

Let me know what I can share.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some more digging, and found a fix.

Maybe someone can comment why this all of a sudden needed added, but I noticed in my names.conf.options file (etc/bind/named.conf.options), in my trusted acl I only had localhost, and for allow-recursion I had {trusted}.

Everything was working fine before, but after updating, I needed to add my local and vpn subnets (x.x.x.0 \24 for both) into the trusted list.

Hopefully this can help someone else!